# Directions Google Map API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-maps

```js
//For TextBox Search..............
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtFrom'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = places.getPlace();
        });
        var places1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtTo'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places1, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place1 = places1.getPlace();
        });
    });

    function calculateRoute(rootfrom, rootto) {
        // Center initialized to Naples, Italy
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.84, 14.25),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        // Draw the map
        var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("DivMap"), myOptions);

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsRequest = {
            origin: rootfrom,
            destination: rootto,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
        };
        directionsService.route(
        directionsRequest,
        function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: mapObject,
                    directions: response
                });
            }
            else
                $("#lblError").append("Unable To Find Root");
        }
    );
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
        if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
            $("#lblError").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
            return;
        }
        $("#calculate-route").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            calculateRoute($("#txtFrom").val(), $("#txtTo").val());
        });
    });
```

```css
#DivMap
{
    border: 1px solid Black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 32%;
}
```

```html
<!--<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script> REMOVED -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

<div style="font-size: 30px; margin: 15px; padding: 15px;">
    Get Direction In Google Map</div>
<hr />
<br />
<div>
    <label for="txtFrom">
        Root From:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtFrom" name="txtFrom" required="required" placeholder="Location From"
        size="40" />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <label for="txtTo">
        Root To:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTo" name="txtTo" required="required" placeholder="Location To"
        size="40" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="reset" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <p id="lblError" style="color: Red; font-size: 17px;" />
</div>
<div id="DivMap">
</div>
```

So I found this source code from the following website for drawing a route line between two geographic locations in google maps using the directions API: http://www.codescratcher.com/javascript/get-directions-google-map-api-using-javascript/

I followed the step-by-type guide and did everything as follows. It seems that there is something wrong with this code. I've tried solving these issues, but it didn't work for me. I think there is something wrong with the API key. Anyone can figure what is causing these issues? Thanks :)

Comment: For one you've included the maps api javascript file twice at the top of your html, one without 'places'

Comment: Get an API key here -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: I don't think i get it @pokeybit

Answer (score 2):

You will need an API Key in order to make the Google Map Live on your Project. You can get a API Key from here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

On your JavaScript part, remove the first Google Map Reference.

Add a JavaScript Code to Initialize your Map first at the beginning of the JavaScript Code.

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('DivMap'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
```

And on the Second Google Map Reference, change your code as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap&key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

Change **YOUR_API_KEY** with the API Key you got.

This will enable your map and you can do your desired thing.

Comment: I did what you said and it did solved the errors, but it not showing any map on the screen. Do you think it's cause of the div? where the map should be displayed? Thanks

Comment: @N.Cre, I have updated my answer. The problem is not the div. You need to initialize the map first before you can start using it.

Answer (score 1):

Grab an API key from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key and place this in your code with your KEY

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Remove all other occurances of `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?`

Answer (score 1):

After adding my own key to check that it works, I found it didn't actually.

```
$("#calculate-route").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculateRoute($("#txtFrom").val(), $("#txtTo").val());
});
```

The above tries to bind the target id "calculate-route" submit event to perform the inner function? Although from what I see, the id "calculate-route" doesn't exist.

Change this:

```
<div>
    <label for="txtFrom">
        Root From:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtFrom" name="txtFrom" required="required" placeholder="Location From"
        size="40" />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <label for="txtTo">
        Root To:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTo" name="txtTo" required="required" placeholder="Location To"
        size="40" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="reset" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <p id="lblError" style="color: Red; font-size: 17px;" />
</div>
```

To this:

```
<form id="calculate-route">
    <label for="txtFrom">
        Root From:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtFrom" name="txtFrom" required="required" placeholder="Location From"
        size="40" />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <label for="txtTo">
        Root To:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTo" name="txtTo" required="required" placeholder="Location To"
        size="40" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="reset" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <p id="lblError" style="color: Red; font-size: 17px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: If this solved your problem/answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)